# How to return only values from SELECT and WHERE IN query?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I have the following table - `orders`:

| id | value | price | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 'orange' | $12 | 7 |
| 8 | 'yellow' | $14 | 29 |
| 5 | 'green' | $17 | 9 |

I have to perform SELECT query with WHERE IN clause

```
SELECT value FROM order WHERE id IN (2, 5);
```

or using Knex.js

```
knex('orders)
      .select('value')
      .whereIn('id', [2, 5])
```

it returns me an array of objects:

```
[{value: 'orange'}, {value: 'green'}]
```

how is it possible to return only array of values using PostgreSQL syntax?

```
['orange', 'green']
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [`pluck`](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#pluck):

```
knex('orders')
      .select('value')
      .whereIn('id', [2, 5])
      .pluck('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT array_agg(value) AS values
FROM orders
WHERE id IN (2, 5);
```

Using Knex.js

```
const values = await knex.raw(`
    SELECT DISTINCT array_agg(value) AS values
    FROM orders
    WHERE id IN (2, 5)
`);
```

Comment: Why using DISTINCT? You almost never need DISTINCT and in your case it can't work anyway. It's just a few extra obsolete characters in your code.